# CRegKey will not open key

Tags: c++, visual-studio, registry

I am migrating some old C++ code that worked on an XP PC to work on a Windows 10 PC.

I am having issues interfacing with the open registry functionality. In the legacy application, I was using the CRegKey functionality from the ATLBASE.H file. Using the same code base that did work on XP, when I step through the code it fails with a return code of 2 (FILE_NOT_FOUND), which indicates that the registry key cannot be found or is unreadable.

I have check the permissions on the registry keys, and set them to FULL ACCESS
Verified that the key location is correct

I am hoping this is not a X86 vs X64 issue, because upgrading this to a 64 bit application would be a difficult proposition. One I am willing to do, but if I can just get this working as is would be best.

After reviewing other examples online, I do not believe it is an issue with the code. I am leaning towards an issue with the registry, or permissions.

Here is my calling function:

```
void doLogFile(bool& test, LPSTR stName)
{
    CRegKey RegKey;
    DWORD v0=0;
    DWORD dwCount=128;
    stName = "";
    test=false;
    bool ress = false;
    long lres = RegKey.Open(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\MyCompany\\MyApp"), KEY_READ);
    // lres returns code 2 here
    if(lres == ERROR_SUCCESS){
        if (RegKey.QueryDWORDValue("LogFile", v0) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            if ((v0) == 1) {
                if (RegKey.QueryStringValue("LogFileName", stName, &dwCount) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
                    strcat_s(stName, (strlen(stName) + 5), ".log");
                    test=true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if(lres==ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND /* or code=2 */) {
        // this is the error code returned
        ress = true;
    }
    else {
        ress = true;
    }
    if(RegKey)RegKey.Close();
}
```

This is one of the last pieces I need to resolve before I can begin my test deployment. These registry entries are really important. I just cannot find out why I cannot open the registry keys.

Comment: If you manually created the reg entries initially did you do so under the syswow64 key?

Comment: 1) See these links: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/registry-redirector, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/registry-reflection, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/shared-registry-keys, 2) Consider using the native Win32 APIs, instead of the ATL "CRegKey" wrappers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-functions

Comment: Alek K, no I did not, but when I did, it now works! Thank you! I wish I could buy you a beer!